# How does a Grid know when to re-layout?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I want to subclass [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/custom-panels-overview) to use the yogalayout library to calculate its children's positions and locations.  I'm following instructions to [create a custom panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/custom-panels-overview).  I see that when a child changes size, Grid knows to do a layout, but my control does not (ie, neither `MeasureOverride` nor `ArrangeOverride()` is called).

How can I know when a child (or, worse, a child of a child) size changes?

I have created a sample project https://github.com/arolson101/PanelTest that reproduces the issue I'm talking about.

(Note: I'm changing the question which previously mentioned StackPanel to instead mention Grid; I'm not convinced that it's unique to the Grid, but that was the way I was able to make a simple repro case.)

Comment: Any updates for this thread?

Comment: Thank you for your response, @NicoZhu-MSFT.  I have created a sample project and updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

> I see that when a child changes size, StackPanel knows to do a layout, but my control does not (ie, neither MeasureOverride nor ArrangeOverride() is called).

If you have not specific width and height property for the children element, when you get it's property, it will return NaN, And you could not set value with `Width = newWidth`, it can't also invoke the size change event, please call [`SetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject.setvalue?view=winrt-19041) method to change the element size like the following. Then it will make `MeasureOverride` invoked.

```
 MyTextBlock.SetValue(WidthProperty, 15);
```